# useState hook updating the component in next render not in the current render

Tags: react-hooks, render

I'm trying to build a sudoku app. You can find my code here : https://codesandbox.io/s/sudoku-ffrstc?file=/src/components/Board.jsx

when i click on the any cell in the board. numbers getting updated in the next render not in the current render. Can anyone help me here.

i want to use the useState hook to be updated immediately. useEffect hook also not working for me. I'm not sure where i'm making mistake.

Comment: that is how react works. the new state will be available only in the next render.

Comment: why don't you elaborate what your actual problem is

Comment: Also, mutating a useRef.current, will not cause a re-render

Comment: Thanks friends for your input. I have read the react useState docs.
Actually while updating a array using useState, we need to create a new array and should not mutate the existing array and pass it to useState hook. Immediate render happened in my case - so my issue resolved 

`wrong code :
board[outerCell][cell] = num
setBoard(board)`

`correct code :
setBoard((board) => {
        const board1 = [...board];
        board1[outerCell][cell] = num;
        return board1;
      });`